# What does "in the phrase of the period" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

From Charlie Chaplin biography book by Peter Ackroyd (page 3),

> *He confided on occasions to his friends that he was not sure of the identity of his biological father; nevertheless he took the name of a successful music-hall artist, Charles Chaplin, who was for a while married to his mother. He once said to an assistant, Eddie Sutherland, that "I don't know, actually, who my father was. He may have been, **in the phrase of the period,** a love child"*

What does "in the phrase of the period" mean here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It means that in the 19th century (Chaplin was born in 1889) 'love child' was a polite euphemism commonly used for a child born out of wedlock.